# Finding correlation among multiple time series

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have a dataset of 5 apps customers spend time on, at weekly grain. One of our apps (say App A) is not performing well.

What I want to achieve is try and find correlation between the declining app and remainder of them. The idea is not to predict in the future, but to see if we can get co-efficients in a regression to break down the time series of A.

A = a + B1(App B) + B2(App C) + B3 (App D) and so on, (something like this)

so that once we have this equation, we can find out if a certain drop in App A's usage is 'normal' (maybe all others are falling, or the ones which are related are falling) or something we need to dig into.

Can anyone suggest a method to do so? All the data is a weekly grain.